# Checking if list item is empty with LINQ at where condition?

Tags: linq

i have a problem with LINQ structure ?

i will fetch the all the list item from Sharepoint customlist.. like following

```
SPList ComponentMaster = Site.Lists[Constants.Lst_CompMaster];

 var products = from SPListItem ci in ComponentMaster .Items
                where ci["Component Name"].ToString().Contains(SearchKey) ||
                      (
                         ( ci["Component Description"] == null &&           
                           !string.IsNullOrEmpty(
                               ci["Component Description"].ToString()
                            )
                       ) ? true:false)
```

Here I want to check whether the component description is null, if true return null/false ,otherwise check whether my SearchKey word in description ?

```
select new
{
    ProductName = ci["Component Name"].ToString(),
    ID = ci.UniqueId.ToString(),
    ItemID = ci.ID.ToString()                                             
} ;


if( products > 0 )
{
    //do somthing..
}
```

by
vadivelu.B

Comment: I'll second that, @user801463 if you want people to put any effort into answering your question, please put a bit of effort into making it clear exactly what you are asking!

Comment: Now that we have corrected your code, what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually give us an explanation of what is wrong we can help.  I did see that this statement is overly complex and contradicts itself..:

```
 var products = from SPListItem ci in ComponentMaster .Items
            where ci["Component Name"].ToString().Contains(SearchKey) ||
                  (
                     ( ci["Component Description"] == null &&           
                       !string.IsNullOrEmpty(
                           ci["Component Description"].ToString()
                        )
                   ) ? true:false)
```

Assuming you want items that have a name or description, it reduces to:

```
 var products = from SPListItem ci in ComponentMaster .Items
            where ci["Component Name"].ToString().Contains(SearchKey) ||   
                  string.IsNullOrEmpty(ci["Component Description"].ToString())
```